# calculate daily average sale from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, subquery

I want to calculate the daily average of sales from my sql table .
I tried using the following query but it gives error saying "Incorrect syntax near keyword select"

```
select avg(select sum(total) from canteen group by date) as average from canteen
```

Comment: did you run this query in your DBMS or in java code? if in code u should to put it in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't nest aggregation functions.  This is what you want to get the sum for each date:

```
select day, sum(total)
from canteen
group by day;
```

You can get the average using a subquery:

```
select avg(total)
from (select day, sum(total) as total
      from canteen
      group by day
     ) c;
```

Or, a simpler alternative:

```
select sum(total) / count(distinct day)
from canteen;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
SELECT date, avg(total) average FROM (
SELECT date, sum(total)total FROM canteen GROUP BY DATE
)AS A
grouP BY date
```

Comment: Now check @MohitJoshi I missed Group By

Answer (score 0):

I prefer if you don't bother about nested query;

```
select avg(total) from(select sum(total) as total from canteen group by date) as T
```

Comment: Any error or wrong result? Updated the query, can you try this one?

Comment: :) .. glad to hear that

Comment: Can u please tell me what is the significance of the alias 'T' in your query because without that it gives an error

Comment: In mysql it is mandatory to add an alias for a sub query table

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you try to use a subquery like this:

```
select avg(total) from(select sum(total) from canteen group by date)
```